# JIRA REST PUT setting a property value

Tags: php, json, rest, curl, jira-rest-api

I am trying to set a property value by sending a cURL PUT to `/rest/api/2/issue/{issue}/worklog/{worklog}/properties/{key}`. I have no idea what kind of data I'm supposed to PUT though, as the Atlassian API reference provides no examples. I've tried some of the following:

```
{
  "value": "test"
}
```

`"test"`

```
{
  "key": "key",
  "value": "test"
}
```

All those attempts return wit the following error:

```
{"errorMessages":["The property value can not be empty."],"errors":{}}
```

I'm using PHP to send the request. Here's the relevant code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
$response = (curl_exec($curl));
curl_close($curl);
```

Can anyone tell me what the correct value is to PUT?

Comment: start with the GET call tot he same resource and it will show you the expected structure that you need to PUT back. Post the results of your GET and we can help further

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late reply. `{"errorMessages":["The property {key} does not exist."],"errors":{}}` is what I get back. I cannot figure out how to create a property, so that's an issue. JIRA documentations says an example reply should look like this, though: `{"key": "issue.support","value": {"hipchat.room.id":support-123","support.time": "1m"}}`. Even if I follow this supposed format to post, though, it returns the same error.

Comment: @KishanKock did you ever figure this out? The Atlassian API docs are just as bad now as they were 6 years ago...